# Centering in IE11 with CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11, css-grid

I am currently attempting to center (both vertically and horizontally) elements via a CSS grid. After some research, it seems IE11 supports css grid via different syntax than more up to date browsers (edge, safari, chrome, etc). I am using the `display:-ms-grid` syntax and this is putting my elements in the top left of the screen instead of centering them as I'd like. Note the posted example does work as expected with other browsers.

```
<div style="height:100%;display:grid;display:-ms-grid;">
     <div style="margin:auto" align="center">
          <img id="logo" alt="Logo" style="width:250px;margin-top:-5%" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,xxxxxxxxxxxxx">
          <div style="margin-top:2%;" class="loader"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

How can I overcome the centering issue for IE11?

**Update:** I've been able to center it vertically but not horizontally so far. This is where I'm currently at:

```
<div style="height:100%;display:grid;display:-ms-grid;-ms-grid-columns:2fr 2fr 2fr;">
     <div style="margin:auto;-ms-grid-column:2;" align="center">
          <img id="logo" alt="Logo" style="width:250px;margin-top:-5%" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,xxxxxxxxxxxxx">
          <div style="margin-top:2%;" class="loader"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I found a working solution to support this in IE 10/11. Basically to define 3 columns and 3 rows for the `-ms-grid` by using `-ms-grid-columns` and `-ms-grid-rows` and then specify that my content I want centered should be in column 2 and row 2 (the middle) by using `-ms-grid-column` and `-ms-grid-row`. Solution as follows:

```
<div style="height:100%;display:grid;display:-ms-grid;-ms-grid-columns:2fr 2fr 2fr;-ms-grid-rows: 2fr 2fr 2fr;">
     <div style="margin:auto;-ms-grid-column:2;-ms-grid-row:2;" align="center">
          <img id="logo" alt="Logo" style="width:250px;margin-top:-5%" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,xxxxxxxxxxxxx">
          <div style="margin-top:2%;" class="loader"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can see that you had posted the solution for your issue. I suggest you to mark that solution as an accepted answer for this thread after 24 hrs may help other community members in future. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I **really** hope you have just inlined your css for brevity. This should at least be in a `<style>` block, or preferably an external CSS resource.

Comment: yes the css is inline here only for demonstration purposes

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.grid-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
  align-content: center
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <img id="logo" alt="Logo" width="250px" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,xxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
</div>
```